# Function to find winning line with NxN board and M pieces in a row in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to create a function that finds if a move is winning on an NxN board where the winning condition is M pieces in a row in Python 3.

I am pretty new to programming and in my specific case I am creating a Gomoku game (15x15 board with 5 pieces in a row to win). To get it working I created 6 for loops to check vertical, horizontal and 4 diagonals. See the code below for examples on the 2 options for left to right digonals. This takes way too long though when I need to loop through it many times (8) for computer to find if I can win or if it has a winning move.

```
    end_row = 15
    for j in range(11):
        end_row -= 1
        counter = 0
        for i in range(end_row):
            if board[i+j][i] == board[i+1+j][i+1] and board[i+j][i] != ' ':
                counter += 1
                if counter == 4:
                    winning_line = [(i+j-3, i-3), (i+j-2, i-2), (i+j-1, i-1), (i+j, i), (i+1+j, i+1)]
                    winner = True
                    break
            else:
                counter = 0

    # Top left to bottom right, lower side
    end_row = 15
    for j in range(11):
        end_row -= 1
        counter = 0
        for i in range(end_row):
            if board[i][i+j] == board[i+1][i+1+j] and board[i][i+j] != ' ':
                counter += 1
                if counter == 4:
                    winning_line = [(i-3, i+j-3), (i-2, i+j-2), (i-1, i+j-1), (i, i+j), (i+1, i+1+j)]
                    winner = True
                    break
            else:
                counter = 0
```

---

```
      # What I want to do instead, where x and y are coordinates of last move:
      # Horizontal
      counter = 0
      for i = x - (n - 1) to  x + (n - 1):
          if board[i][y] == board[x][y] :
              counter++
          else :
              counter = 0
          if counter == n:
              return true
```

The problem with the lower part of the code is that if I place a piece on e.g. position (0, 0) the program will complain when trying to reach board[-4][0] in the first looping. I will have to place lots of if statements when I get close to the edge, which is not an elegant solution.

I thought of making a 3*15 x 3*15 board instead, where the actual board is the inner 15x15 part and the rest just contains placeholders:

### 15x15  ||   15x15   ||   15x15

### 15x15  ||   board   ||   15x15

### 15x15  ||   15x15   ||   15x15

This to avoid getting outside of my list of lists when looping through. Not an elegant solution either, but takes less space in the code.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance from a beginner programmer!

Comment: You can simply use min and max function to place boundary limits for all checks : `for i = max(x - (n - 1), 0) to  min(x + (n - 1), 15)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MePsyDuck mentioned in comments, you can use `min` and `max` functions to limit the range to only reference valid squares in the `board` matrix.

Furthermore, you could make a generic function that does the count-job on any given list of values. Then you can call that generic function four times: once for every direction (horizontal, vertical, diagonal \ and diagonal /)

Here is how that could work:

```py
def is_win(board, n, x, y):
    end_row = len(board)
    color = board[x][y]

    def check(values):
        counter = 0
        for value in values:
            if value == color:
                counter += 1
            else:
                counter = 0
            if counter == n:
                return True
        return False

    return (check([board[i][y] for i in range(max(0, x - n + 1), min(end_row, x + n))])
        or check([board[x][i] for i in range(max(0, y - n + 1), min(end_row, y + n))])
        or check([board[x+i][y+i] for i in range(max(-x, -y, 1 - n), min(end_row - x, end_row - y, n))])
        or check([board[x+i][y-i] for i in range(max(-x, y - end_row + 1, 1 - n), min(end_row - x, y + 1, n))]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, this will help me greatly! :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping from 0 to 14, just loop from 0 to (board_size - winning_length).

Here's an example for a 1-dimensional board:

```
BOARD_SIZE = 15
WINNING_LENGTH = 5

for x in range(BOARD_SIZE - WINNING_LENGTH):
    players_here = set()
    for pos in range(x, x + WINNING_LENGTH):
        players_here.add(board[pos])
    if len(players_here) == 1:
        # Exactly 1 player occupies every position in this line, so they win
```

Comment: That's what first part of his code does. I think he needs a way to only check `player_pos - WINNING_LENGTH` to `player_pos + WINNING_LENGTH`. Correct me if I'm wrong.